# getting Connected host wall elements

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have a bunch of doors connected to a single wall element.
I've tried to get all the door properties by using getProperties() but I couldn`t find the Id of is wall host.
Is there any way to get the ID of the wall?

Answer (score 0):

***Walls*** and ***Doors*** end up in two different categories when exported to Forge and loaded in the viewer. So there is no parent-child relationship that you can determine automatically. Also a door doesn't have a wall property where it belongs to.

You would need to write this relationship with custom Revit properties, so they can be exported to Forge and you can access them programmatically.

Other way would be a geometric approach, looking if the door bounding box is inside the wall bonding box, but it can be costly performance wise and not 100% accurate.

[image]